# What is the use of ServiceRegistry in creating SessionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, sessionfactory

I am learning Hibernate in Java.
Since, to create a `Session`, we have to use `SessionFactory.openSession()`, and for creating `SessionFactory` we use `sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);`

What is the use of `ServiceRegistry` in hibernate??

My code for creating `SessionFactory` :

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.addAnnotatedClass(user.class);
        config.addAnnotatedClass(emp.class);
        config.configure();

// Didn't understand the code below
            Properties configProperties = config.getProperties();
            ServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegisteryBuilder = new ServiceRegistryBuilder();
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegisteryBuilder.applySettings(configProperties).buildServiceRegistry();
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

Answer (score 4):

A ServiceRegistry, at its most basic, hosts and manages Services. Its contract is defined by the org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry interface.
Currently Hibernate utilizes 3 different ServiceRegistry implementations forming a hierarchy.

- BootstrapServiceRegistry
- StandardServiceRegistry
- SessionFactoryServiceRegistry
  org.hibernate.service.spi.SessionFactoryServiceRegistry is the 3rd standard Hibernate ServiceRegistry. Typically, its parent registry is the StandardServiceRegistry. SessionFactoryServiceRegistry is designed to hold Services which need access to the SessionFactory. Currently that is just 3 Services.

**EventListenerRegistry**
org.hibernate.event.service.spi.EventListenerRegistry is the big Service managed in the SessionFactoryServiceRegistry. This is the Service that manages and exposes all of Hibernate’s event listeners. A major use-case for Integrators is to alter the listener registry.

If doing custom listener registration, it is important to understand the org.hibernate.event.service.spi.DuplicationStrategy and its effect on registration. The basic idea is to tell Hibernate:

what makes a listener a duplicate

how to handle duplicate registrations (error, first wins, last wins)

**StatisticsImplementor**

org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor is the SPI portion of the org.hibernate.stat.Statistics API. The collector portion, if you will.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer Hibernate documentation (chapter 7) : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch07.html

Service : Services are classes that provide Hibernate with pluggable implementations of various types of functionality. Specifically they are implementations of certain service contract interfaces

ServiceRegistry : The central service API, aside from the services themselves, is the org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry interface. The main purpose of a service registry is to hold, manage and provide access to services.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this : 
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch07.html

The central service API, aside from the services themselves, is the org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry interface. The main purpose of a service registry is to hold, manage and provide access to services.

Service registries are hierarchical. Services in one registry can depend on and utilize services in that same registry as well as any parent registries.

Use org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder to build a org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry instance.